# Stockholm Arlanda Airport transfer

Tags: airport-transfer, sweden, arn

How do you get to and from Arlanda Airport? Are there busses, trains or even flights connecting Arlanda with Stockholm? Is it possible to take a taxi to Stockholm?

Comment: You can actually stay indoors all the trip between Stockholm and London if you choose a way that is indoors all the way.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz if you can call the Arlanda Express platform at Stockholm Central "indoors" you could stay at a hotel at the station and then go back to London - all without being outdoors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, there are several options.

- Taxi: There are always taxis available outside the terminals. A ride to the city center is about 500 SEK (approximately 50 EUR). The ride takes 30-60 minutes depending on the amount of traffic.
- [Flygbussarna](https://www.flygbussarna.se/en) (airport coaches). Has several routes depending on what part of Stockholm you're going to. A single ticket from Arlanda to Stockholm city is 99 SEK (approximately 10 EUR). The ride takes 50-60 minutes.
- Flixbus. Pretty much the same as *Flygbussarna* but cheaper. Tickets start at 39 SEK.
- [Public transport in Stockholm](http://sl.se/en) (1): You can take a bus to Märsta, followed by a regular commuter train to Stockholm City. Note that if you buy e.g. a 72-hour ticket for unlimited travel in Stockholm, going to Stockholm City this way is included. It also takes the longest time, 75 - 90 minutes depending on the connections.
- [Public transport in Stockholm](http://sl.se/en) (2): You can pay to access the commuter trains immediately at Arlanda. This costs 150 SEK (approximately 15 EUR) for a single ticket including passage, and the ride takes 40 minutes.
- [Arlanda Express](https://www.arlandaexpress.com/), a train departing up to six times per hour. An adult ticket is 280 SEK (approximately 28 EUR) and a youth ticket is 165 SEK. The ride takes 20 minutes.

Comment: Worth noting that the Flygbussarna are rather nicer than average for airport buses: they’re typically clean, well-maintained, and have reliable wi-fi.  Indeed, Stockholm public transport is generally pretty nice.

Comment: Jesus Christ, the local train access fee's gone up by 47% since I last visited my hometown! Good thing that minors are exempt - and if you look young and confidently state you're 16-17, they'll usually let you through no questions asked (so far without exception for me). Also the entrance is unstaffed and the gates open between midnight and 6AM

Comment: @Crazydre yeah, I think the fees are rather ridiculous. If you already have a valid ticket (e.g. 72-hour or monthly) it's 120 SEK, but it's still quite a lot. I've also been able to avoid the fees by going to Arlanda early, before the entrance is staffed.

Comment: @HenricF And allegedly the fee was "temporarily" introduced (with the launch of Upptaaget from Väsby) to pay off the debts stemming from the construction of Arlandabanan. Been over a decade now and they only keep raising it...

Comment: @Crazydre Almost. The station and railway for Arlandabanan is owned an run by a private company, and can basically charge all other companies (including public transport) whatever they want for the rights to use the tracks and the station. See http://www.dn.se/sthlm/kraftig-prishojning-for-att-aka-tag-till-flyget/ (in Swedish).

Comment: I travelled from and back to Arlanda with Taxi Stockholm and both drivers were very helpful and accommodating to my infant son and charged 500Kr each. I was also advised by my Swedish grandmother-in-law (who lives in Stockholm) that Taxi Kurir are reliable and trust-worthy - but that's not from personal experience. Once you're in Stockholm and its' suburbs the underground is a fast and cost effective way to travel. It's not as large as the London Underground but it's reliable.

Comment: @HenricF "Politiker i landstinget anser att det blir dyrt och leder till ökad biltrafik" You don't say...if not for me being able to lie at the station gate I honestly don't know how I'd travel to/from the airport. Via Märsta it takes far too long.

Comment: Note that taxi prices in Sweden are not regulated, so the can charge however much they want. Check the price before going, or use one of the large firms (and watch out others with deceptively similar names.

Answer (score 3):

The information on [wikipedia's page on Arlanda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arlanda) is good. In short: there are buses, commuter trains and high speed trains.